# How to marshall non-string objects with JAXB and Spring

Tags: xml, spring, object, jaxb

I was trying to follow [this](http://eggsylife.co.uk/2010/01/03/spring-3-restful-web-services/) tutorial in order to create my own restful web-service using Spring framework.
The client do a GET request to, let's say

> http://api.myapp/app/students

and the server returns an xml version of the object classroom:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "class")
    public class Classroom {

    private String classId = null;
    private ArrayList<Student> students = null;

    public Classroom() {
    }
    public String getClassId() {
        return classId;
    }
    public void setClassId(String classId) {
        this.classId = classId;
    }
    @XmlElement(name="student")
    public ArrayList<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }
    public void setStudents(ArrayList<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }
    }
```

The object Student is another bean containing only Strings.

In my app-servlet.xml i copied this lines:

```
<bean id="studentsView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
    <constructor-arg ref="jaxbMarshaller" />
</bean>

<!-- JAXB2 marshaller. Automagically turns beans into xml -->
<bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>com.spring.datasource.Classroom</value>
            <value>com.spring.datasource.Student</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now my question is: what if i wanted to insert some non-string objects as class variables? Let's say i want a tag containing the String version of an InetAddress, such as

```
<inetAddress>192.168.1.1</inetAddress>
```

How can i force JAXB to call the method inetAddress.toString() in such a way that it appears as a String in the xml? In the returned xml non-string objects are ignored!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `XmlAdapter` to control how an object is converted to from XML.  In your `XmlAdapter` you will write the logic to convert your object to/from a `String`.

**Example**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Blaise and to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720031/how-to-set-jaxb2marshaller-list-of-xmladapters-in-spring-bean-through-xml) answer I managed to set up everything. Just to put them together, here's my case:

The object device was:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="device")
public class Device {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String location;

    private InetSocketAddress address;
    private InetSocketAddress gatewayAddress;

    (omitted setters and getters...)        
}
```

The InetSockeAddressAdapter:

```
public class InetSocketAddressAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, InetSocketAddress>{
    @Override
    public String marshal(InetSocketAddress v) throws Exception {
        return v.toString();
    }
    @Override
    public InetSocketAddress unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        String[] comp = v.split(":");
        return new InetSocketAddress(comp[0], new Integer(comp[1]));
    }

}
```

The package-info.java into the package of both the object and the adapter (created with eclipse as a simple file because the IDE didn't allow me to create a class named package-info):

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
            @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=InetSocketAddress.class, 
                value=InetSocketAddressAdapter.class)})
package com.enrico.apiserver.domain;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
```

The *-servlet.xml rows in which we must declare our beans:

```
<bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <list>
                <value>com.enrico.apiserver.domain.Device</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="adapters">
            <list>
                <bean class="com.enrico.apiserver.domain.InetSocketAddressAdapter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```